# Cut and Paste a row into subsequent rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have data where I need a row of data appended to subsequent rows of data. The row of data I have needs the row with cell in column A where the number of characters equals 9. See below for code:

```
Sub cut_paste()

Dim nr As Integer
For nr = 1 To 195

If Len(Range("A" & nr)) = 9 Then

Range("A" & nr).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("N" & nr).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B" & nr).Select
Selection.Cut

Range("O" & nr).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next nr

End Sub
```

Here is my data:

```
Name    type    location    store   Unit    Qty Cur Over Qty    Unit    Number  Cur Net Cur Material    Desc    Store   Store Name  XYZ
123456789   credit card wc76    walmart                                                     
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         

123456789   credit card wc76    walmart                                                     
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         

123456789   credit card wc76    walmart                                                     
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         

123456789   credit card wc76    walmart                                                     
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY                         
981276WYETD 2   wc76    8   qw  45  JPY 12  qw  90  JPY
```

I needed cell A2 to be copied into cell N2, cell B2 to O2, and to keep copying until a blank row is reached and then start over with the next A column cell that has 9 characters.

Comment: Please format your data insert properly. This may mean using a tool like a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a markdown table you can copy paste into your question using [edit]. Then highlight the table and press Ctrl + K to enter between code tags and voilà.